# Need to highlight overlapping text using PHP

Tags: php, regex, highlighting

I am looking for means to highlight certain text on a page. I use `<span class="highlight">This is a sample</span>` to replace the text "This is a sample" that is found, with the help of the preg_replace function.

My problem arises when there is overlapping text. If I search for the phrase "sample text" on the same page, it is not highlighted. I need the highlighting to merge.

Any help with this problem would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you can provide the code you are currently using, and please explain more about "overlapping" text and merging highlighting.

Comment: Are you saying that if on your first search, you look for *This is a sample*, and the page contains *This is a sample text block* you want to return this: `<span class="highlight">This is a sample</span> text block`, and that if you then search for *sample text* on the same page, you want to return this: `<span class="highlight">This is a <span class="highlight">sample text</span></span> block` - a nested highlight? Or do you want the second highlight to expand upon the first: `<span class="highlight">This is a sample text</span> block` ?

Comment: I want the second highlight to expand upon the first in this manner: <span class ="highlight">This is a sample text<span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't replace text. Find positions of texts that need highlighting, sort them by beginnings and check if in that ordered list item's begining of next item "overlaps" ending of previous.

Text:
`This is a sample text.`
`0123456789...`
Items to highlight: `This is` and `is a`.

Ordered list I'm talking about: `[[0, 7], [5, 9]]`. 5 and 7 "ovrelap".

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be a great suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand your needs, I think you need to split all sentences giving you words and then you can highlighten them individualy.